# One List of Users for 2 TabItem

Tags: java, android, android-tablayout, tabitem

I have a `List` of `Users` with 2 `TabItem`. The first `TabItem` is `MyUsers` and the second one is `Favorites`. I use a `foreach` loop to sort the `Users`. Now, that I want, is to display the `Users` `List` into `MyUsers` and after my loop display the sorted `Users` into `Favorites`.

UserFragment.java

```
public class UserFragment extends Fragment implements MyUserRecyclerViewAdapter.OnItemListener {

@BindView(R.id.tabs)
TabLayout mTabLayout;
@BindView(R.id.tabItem)
TabItem mTabItemMyUsers;
@BindView(R.id.tabItem2)
TabItem mTabItemFavorites;

private UserApiService mApiService;
private List<User> mUsers;
private List<User> mFavorites;
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

private int mPosition;

public static UserFragment newInstance(int position) {
    UserFragment userFragment = new UserFragment();

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("position", position);
    userFragment.setArguments(args);

    return userFragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mApiService = DI.getUserApiService();

    mPosition = getArguments().getInt("position", 0);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_user_list, container, false);
    Context context = view.getContext();
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view;
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
    mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getContext(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));

    initList();
    isUserFavorite();
    return view;
}


public void isUserFavorite() {
    mFavorites = new ArrayList<>();

    for (User user : mUsers) {
        if (user.isFavorite()) {
            mFavorites.add(user);
        }
    }
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(new MyUserRecyclerViewAdapter(mFavorites, this));

}

private void initList() {
    mUser = mApiService.getUsers();
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(new MyUserRecyclerViewAdapter(mUsers, this));

}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
}
```

Comment: For these kind of questions it is generally required that you display / list things that you tried, otherwise it comes down to a code request rather than a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question right. You will be creating two lists, one unordered list of users as received and second with list of users marked as favorites. And then you want to switch which list to show in the single `RecyclerView` in your fragment's layout by clicking on one of the two tabs in your `TabLayout` in the same layout.

You should simply populate the lists first instead of setting them both into RecyclerView at once, then manage tab selections on your `mTabLayout` using an `addOnTabSelectedListener` inside which you can choose the list to set into your recyclerview, since you have already defined a `LayoutManager` for your list, next finally use `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your adapter to to update the views.

So keeping most of your logic the same your code would need to be refactored to something like this:

```
...
@Override
public View onCreateView(La...) {
...
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
...
    initList();
    isUserFavorite();
    initSelection();
    return view;
}

public void isUserFavorite() {
    mFavorites = new ArrayList<>();
    for (User user : mUsers) {
        if (user.isFavorite()) {
            mFavorites.add(user);
        }
    }    
}

private void initList() {
    mUser = mApiService.getUsers();    
}


public void initSelection() {
  mTabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        // assuming users is at tab index 0 and favorites is at tab Index 1
        if(tab.getPosition() == 1) {
            selectFavorites();
        } else {
            selectUsers();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
    }
  });
  // if you wish to select the users tab at 0 by default
  Objects.requireNonNull(mTabLayout.getTabAt(0)).select();
}

private void selectFavorites() {
    // whichever adapter you were using to show favorites
    MyUserRecyclerViewAdapter mFavAdapter = new MyUserRecyclerViewAdapter(mFavorites, context);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mFavAdapter);
    mFavAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

private void selectUsers() {
    // whichever adapter you were using to show all users
    MyNeighbourRecyclerViewAdapter mUsersAdapter = new MyNeighbourRecyclerViewAdapter(mUsers, context);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mUsersAdapter);
    mFavAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Hope this was what you were looking for.

Comment: Yes you understood very well. Thank you very much for the answer. I will try it tomorrow. I will send you a message tomorrow for tell you if it's work.